# SKMaps.h header file not found

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, skmaps

So I'm using skobbler/scoutmaps version 2.3 and I'm trying to include skmaps with SKMaps like so:

```
#import <SKMaps.h>
```

But I'm getting a SKMaps.h file not found error. In my pod I see that file and I've tried changing my header search paths but it's not working. Any help or ideas as to why this is happening would be appreciated. The other header files from skobbler and the other pods seem to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out it's supposed to be #import  in case anyone else ran into the same issue.